# sh: git: not found || Could not authenticate against github.com

Tags: git, docker, github, composer-php

> sh: git: not found   ||  Could not authenticate against github.com

Above was the error I was getting from a make rebuild command that runs a bunch of stuff, the solution that I/we used to solve that was to add Git personal access token to work mac keychain and then add

```js
"config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "github-oauth": {
            "github.com": "foobar"
        }
    }
```

github-oauth to my composer.json so that the work project builds, then I've deleted the github-oauth from the composer.json so the project is up and I can code away, but my issue is that this is going to happen at the next rebuild.

Basically my question is - how do you authenticate against github with a personal access token, on a shared project that is Dockerised? I expect the answer is to have your personal access token in an env for each user locally stored, but I am a junior and am not sure how you would go about this.

It is built in circle-ci so could we share a github account and store the personal access token in the env of there? I don't want my personal access token to become public / remote of course.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate against the API or are you trying to perform Git operations?

Comment: Authenticate against the api in part of a build. Solution was to apply a personal access token as a local env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I handle this situation, create a file containing the auth token and this file should not be commited to your vcs, here is an example for git:

```
//.gitignore
docker/php/auth.json
```

```js
//docker/php/auth.json
{
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "YOUR_TOKEN"
    }
}
```

```bash
# Dockerfile
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

#Copy your token
COPY docker/php/auth.json /root/.composer/auth.json

#Then you can call composer
composer install
```

Projet structure:

```
docker/
    php/
        auth.json
.gitignore
Dockerfile
```

Hope this help

Comment: Yep, this would do it :)